# Mogodb update() deprecated...having trouble with updateOne()

Tags: mongodb

I have the following code:

```
apiTalon.forEach(talon => {    
        var apiTalonID = talon.ACTIVITY_ID
        var filter = {'ACTIVITY_ID': apiTalonID}
        var newData = talon

        dbo.collection(collectionName).update(
            filter, 
            newData,
            {upsert:true}, 

            function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(res)
                db.close();    
            }
        )    
    })
```

I get the following error:

> DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead

If I change `update()` to `updateOne()`, then I get:

> MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

I'm not very familiar with Mongo, and I'm sure this is just a syntax or formatting issue that I can't see. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Actually, yes.  I found that article earlier, but I must have fat-fingered something, because trying it again, it's all good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changed code to this and it works fine... $set was the key:

```
apiTalon.forEach(talon => {    
    var apiTalonID = talon.ACTIVITY_ID
    var filter = {'ACTIVITY_ID': apiTalonID}
    var newData = talon

    dbo.collection(collectionName).update(
        filter, 
        {$set:newData},
        {upsert:true}, 

        function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(res)
            db.close();    
        }
    )    
})
```